# How to stop Drupal for setting node changed date on creation?

Tags: 7, nodes

This is my second question about my issues with creating custom migration script.

I am creating only new nodes and don't care about updates.

Code:

```
        $node = new stdClass();
        $node->type = 'migrate';
        $node->title = $content['title'];
        $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

        $node->created = (int) date('U',strtotime($content['created']));

        $modified = $content['modified'];               
        if (! empty($modified) && $modified != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
            $modified = (int) date('U',strtotime($modified));
        } else {
            $modified = 0;
        }               
        $node->changed = $modified;

        node_object_prepare($node);

        #some lines later
        node_save($node);
```

E.g my $modified is set to 0 and after save I see updated column of this node row in admin content list with current datetime value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to preserve the original `changed` time by first setting a custom property on the node object, say `$node->modified`, in your migration script prior to calling `node_save()`, and then implementing the node_presave hook:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave().
 */
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  $node->changed = $node->modified;
}
```

This will work since [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) sets `$node->changed` prior to calling all modules which implement `hook_node_presave()`.

Comment: Yes it works 100% :)

Comment: Suspect I'll get shot down for this, but if like me you're running a short-lived script via drush that's not part of a module and you don't want to implement a module just to implement a hook etc. then it works to `db_query('UPDATE {node} SET created=:created, changed=:changed WHERE nid=:nid', array(':created'=>$whatever,':changed'=>$whatever,':nid'=>$node->nid));` after saving.

Comment: I hate that we have to do something as awkward as a hook (awkward because the change happens in a completely different code segment), but that's drupal's fault, not yours. +1

Comment: You can also use `$node->original->changed` instead of setting a custom property like `$node->modified`. Disable the module after using otherwise the changed date will never be updated.